# How to create a single MySQL database server shared between more than two mirth-connect servers?

Tags: mysql, database, mirth

I am new to mirth-connect. I am using `mirthconnect-3.0.1.7051.b1075` for Linux machine with MySQL as Database. I have two mirth-connect servers.
I want to establish a single MySQL database server which is shared between two or more than two mirth-connect servers. Is it possible ?
If yes, then how can I achieve it ?
Or is there any other alternative to achieve this ?

Comment: What is the motivation for this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for some sort of fail over?

I'm presuming that you want two identical Mirth environments?

These servers would need to be isolated from each other network wise or you'd have conflicts.

If you're looking for clustering,  you could look at Mirth Corp's Mirth appliances.   They have excellent load balancing and clustering.

If you're looking for something homegrown,  you'd need separate environments with database synchronization and network fail over.

This is a very complicated endeavour.